# Как правильно: праздник Ивана Купала(-ы)?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: праздник Ивана Купал**а**(-**ы**),
               ночь на Ивана Купал**у**(-**ы**),
               празднование Ивана Купал**а**(-**ы**).
Ссылаясь на какие правила пишем то или иное окончание?

Answer (score 2):

Считается, что правильное народное название святого - Иван **Купала** (канонически - Иоан Предтеча). Поэтому: ***"ночь накануне Ивана Купалы***", как и во всех остальных ваших примерах.
Но: ***"на Ивана Купалу"*** (здесь винительный падеж).

При этом кое-где настаивают на исходном ***"Иван Купало"***, что более соответствует и исходному имениннику этого дня - Яриле (в именительном - Ярило) из славянского пантеона, и семантике суффикса -ло. Мыло - моет, рыло - роет, купало - купает. Ярило, кстати, - тот, кто "ярит": от "ярый", "ярость" - как эпитет зенита лета.

Поскольку праздник исходно языческий, к святому привязан искусственно, Церковь такие вещи не регулирует. В таком варианте приходится говорить ***"на Ивана Купало"***, ***"накануне Ивана Купала"*** и т.д. Наложение этих двух вариантов и приводит к путанице.

(+)
Да, забыл.
Вариант "ночь на Ивана Купалы" (из предлагаемых Вами) совершенно невозможен. 
Он порожден неверной трактовкой "Купалы" как притяжательного местоимения (чей?). Но такое в принципе исключается, "Иван Купалы" в именительном нигде не фиксируется и смыслу имени (прозвища) никак не соответствует. Иван - не чей, не какого-то Купалы. Он сам **купает**.

Answer (score 1):

Склонение фамилий подчиняется правилам грамматики русского языка. Примечание. Народное название праздника Иванова дня - Иван Купала. Его следует склонять: на Ивана Купалу, под Ивана Купалу, с Иваном Купалой, об Иване Купале.              http://studall.org/all-39601.html

Comment: Купала - не фамилия. Хотя не в том дело. Иван Купала или Купало.  И тут мнения могут расходиться.